# Difference between closure and closed cover of a set

Tags: analysis

IIUC an open cover of a set X is defined as a set of open sets which contain the set X. The closure is the union of the set and the limit points. It seems that a closed cover of a set, i.e. a set of closed sets which contain the set X and the closure are similar sets or the same set.

Do you agree?

For example: The set (0,1) has closed cover [0,1] which is the same as the closure.

Please apologize if I got it wrong because the concepts are new to me.

Comment: No, a closed cover should be a *set* of closed subsets which *together* cover $X$. What you might think is that the one element set $\{\bar X\} $ is a particular closed cover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closure of a set $A$ in topology is defined as the intersection of closed sets containing $A$.  Basically, in topology, intersection of closed sets is closed. Since intersection of two sets is smaller than the two sets, one can see that the closure of a set $A$ is the "smallest closed set containing $A$".

However, not every closed set containing $A$ is its closure. For example, the closure of $(0,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is $[0,1]$. $[-1,2]$ is also a closed set containing $A$ but it's not its closure.

Also, note that opennness and closedness are relative properties in topology. The set $(0,1]$ is open in the topology induced on $[0,1]$ from $\mathbb{R}$, but it is not open in $\mathbb{R}$. Similarly, $(0,1]$ is closed in $(0,2)$ in the topology induced on $(0,2)$ in $\mathbb{R}$, but it is not closed in $\mathbb{R}$. So, it's very important to remember that when you talk about openness or closedness, you should always pay attention to your ambient space. Plus, the closure of a set also depends on the ambient space. For example, the closure of $(0,1)$ in $(0,2)$ is $(0,1]$ which is not open in $\mathbb{R}$.

Read about the [subspace topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology) on Wikipedia to understand this stuff better. Also, read theorems $2.24$, $2.27$ and $2.30$ in Rudin's mathematical analysis.

Comment: But is it true about a "minimal closed cover" ?

Comment: @NiklasRosencrantz  using the word "minimal" can be a bit tricky here. If you cover $A$ in two different ways with closed sets, their intersection still covers $A$ and is closed but is smaller. As I said, the closure of $A$ is the "smallest" closed set that covers $A$.

Answer (score 1):

For $(0,1),$ by you definition, since each point is closed, the set itself would also be a closed cover.